# How to show array items as a table head inline using VUE.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an array with 4`enter code here` element. I want to show them as a table head. when i run a v-for loop the items prints element every line but i want them in one line. how can i do that ?

Comment: Please include a piece of code for reference

Comment: Create inline/inline-block containers for the array items. This is related to the display property of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="header in TableHeaders">
            {{header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I do same but it still showing in different line

<thead>
    <tr v-for="name in names">
        <th scope="col">{{name}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

Comment: Because you create a new <tr> row for each entry, and a row is displayed as a block. You need a single row and inside that row a cell for each entry. Move the v-for on the <th>.